# Twitter Bootstrap Multiselect - Set Default Value

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

Using Bootstrap Multiselect (http://davidstutz.github.io/bootstrap-multiselect/#templates) and I can't seem to set the default value for the multiselect per the documentation.  I'm doing this inside a function:

```
$("#selector").multiselect("select", ["Value1"]);
$("#selector").multiselect("refresh");
```

This should be relatively simple, but doesn't appear to work. Has anyone else been able to set a default?

Comment: Shouldn't it be `.multiselect("select", "Value1");` (not an array)?

Comment: Documentation shows an array: $('#example-select').multiselect('select', ['1', '2', '4']); - I did try without and it makes no difference.

Comment: The reason for the array is so that multiple options can be picked as well.  In my case, I just wanna pick one! :)

Comment: What if you add `true` as a third argument? Does it work?

Comment: No doesn't work and neither does: .multiselect('select', value, triggerOnChange); that's from the documentation too.

Answer (score 0):

Well, this is annoying but this is what works:

```
window.setTimeout(function () {
    try { setTimeout(
    $("#selector").multiselect("select", ["Value1"]), 0); } catch (err) { }
}, 0);
```

Weird. :-/

Comment: I also had to deselect the existing radio button option: $("#selector").multiselect("deselect", ["Value0"]), 0);

Comment: The probably is in other part of your code, can you post more info?

your commands are inside $(function(){}); ?